# How to get checkbox and textbox value from HTML table using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a dynamically created HTML table with values- Partial View
There are two TextBoxes for 'Quantity' and 'Remarks'
and one checkbox

```
  <table style="border:0;width:100%;padding:5px" class="table_style" id="mytable">
    <tbody>
             @for (int i = 0; i < dtServices.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
             {           
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:left;vertical-align:top">                
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ServiceListDetails.UserXId, new { Id = "hduId", Value = userId })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ServiceListDetails.SessionXId, new { Id = "hdsId", Value = HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"] })     
                            @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.ServiceListDetails.Id, new { @Id = "hdServiceId",Value = @dtServices.Rows[i]["ServiceId"].ToString() })  </td>

                            @* <td style="text-align:left;vertical-align:top">@dtServices.Rows[i]["ServiceId"].ToString()</td> *@
                            <td style="text-align:left;vertical-align:top">@dtServices.Rows[i]["ServiceName"].ToString()</td>
                            <td style="text-align:left;vertical-align:top">@dtServices.Rows[i]["ServiceUnit"].ToString()</td>

                            <td style="text-align:left;vertical-align:top">@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.ServiceListDetails.ServicelistQuatity, new { @Id = "txtQty_" + @dtServices.Rows[i]["ServiceId"].ToString(), @style = "width:120px" })</td>
                            <td style="text-align:left;vertical-align:top">@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.ServiceListDetails.ServicelistRemarks, new { @Id = "txtRemark_" + @dtServices.Rows[i]["ServiceId"].ToString(), @style = "width:200px" })</td>
                            <td>@Html.CheckBox("assignids")</td>    
                            <td style="text-align:left;vertical-align:top">

                        </td>
                    </tr>
             }
     </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to get the values of the the selected rows by getting the selected row and the corresponding values in the textboxes using jquery on click of button in View

```
  <input type="button" id="btnPreview" name="Preview" value=" Preview " class="button"/>
```

I tried googling and came to this. But still not working.The values are 'undefined'

```
    $("#btnPreview").click(function () {
     var strmsg = "Values = ";
     var rows = $('#mytable tbody >tr');
     var columns;
     for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
         columns = $(rows[i]).find('td');
         for (var j = 0; j < columns.length; j++) {

             if ($(columns[j]).find('assignids').is(':checked'))
             {
                 var itemcode = $(columns[j]).find('txtQty_').val();
                 strmsg = strmsg + itemcode;
             }
         }
     }
```

Please anyone help me.. I have been stuck with this for more than a week now :-(((

Any help appreciated.

Comment: when you console.log(strmsg);  what you got?

Comment: Its returning 'Undefined'..

Comment: could you please show HTML code result from this code `@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.ServiceListDetails.ServicelistRemarks, new { @Id = "txtRemark_" + @dtServices.Rows[i]["ServiceId"].ToString(), @style = "width:200px" })`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$(rows[i])` and `$(columns[j])`, have you tried using jQuery's `eq()` method instead?

Here's a good resource for it: http://api.jquery.com/eq/